# Files in WindowsPhone Silverlight using ---- var resource = Application.GetResourceStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows Phone and Silverlight. I am in the process of completing two phone apps in C#. However I have an issue with files for windows phone. Whenever I search google for information on files with Silverlight for windows phone I come across the same code I have been using. Whenever I run these lines of code:

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("dictionary.txt", UriKind.Relative));
dictionary = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
```

`resource` is always `null` and therefore my apps crash. `dictionary` is declared as a `StreamReader` and I have placed my text file in the same location as `MainPage.xaml.cs` (C# source file). Could somebody please point out my error?

Answer (score 4):

I believe `GetResourceStream` returns null if the resource cannot be found, though the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) doesn't say either way.

Try the following (assuming `dictionary.txt` is in the root folder of your main project):

1. Ensure the build mode of `dictionary.txt` is set to `Resource` (not `Embedded Resource`) in the properties window (select it, hit `F4`)
2. Try calling `GetResourceStream` with a fully qualified Uri: `new Uri("/Project.Name;component/dictionary.txt", UriKind.Relative)`

Comment: Thanks, this works! I did not know that I had to add my text file into my project, unlike C++

Comment: @codeMasterFiveThousand - If you don't mind, marking this question as the answer (by clicking the tick on the left), will prevent it from showing up in the "unanswered" section of the site.